# How to set number of mapper equal to number of regions in custom TableInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I have a custom tableinputformat for hbase with getSplits() overridden

```
public List<InputSplit> getSplits(JobContext context) throws IOException 
{
 List<InputSplit> splits = new ArrayList<InputSplit>(); 
 for (Scan scan : scans) {
   List<InputSplit> localSplits = null;
   setScan(scan);
   localSplits = super.getSplits(context);

   splits.addAll(localSplits);
 }
 return splits;
}
```

Here I would like to set the number of map task equal to the number of regions. How do I restrict the number of maps?

Comment: IF your are using TableInputFormat, the number of splits returned by `getSplits` should be the number of this table's regions.

Comment: i have 12 regions (pre split using bucket) but MR job is creating 22 maps for 1500 rows. each map is CPU intensive and most of the maps don't do anything.

Comment: You can check the source codes here: http://www.grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.hbase/hbase/0.94.11/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableInputFormatBase.java#150

Comment: Where did you get the number of regions? From the HBase web monitor? Is it a url like `http://example.com:60010/table.jsp?name=your_table_name`

Comment: as mentioned earlier i did a pre split of 12 regions

Comment: and i see 12 regions at the url you mentioned